# Micronaut, Serdeable and Kotlin data classes with default values

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I have tried to switch to `micronaut-serde-jackson` from `micronaut-jackson-databind` both with Micronaut 3.9.x and again with Micronaut 4.0.0.

The problem arises when trying to deserialize JSON to Kotlin data classes with fields with default values, and when those fields are missing in the JSON. Example:

```
@Serdeable
data class MainAggregationVm(
    val someProp: List<ClassificationAndStats> = emptyList()
)
```

When using `jacksonObjectMapper` there are no issues. When a field is missing in JSON, default value `emptyList()` is used.

Errors are on this form:

io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Error decoding HTTP
response body: Error decoding JSON stream for type ...
... problem: Parameter specified as non-null is null

**Update 2023-7-23**

We have 50+ data classes in library repos, and we need to use `@SerdeImport` for all of these in 7 apps.

I also noticed that for every enum class like this

```
enum class Aggregation(private val descripton: String) {
    SOMETHING_1("Some description #1"),
    SOMETHING_2("Some description #2")
}
```

we'll have to implement a `TypeConverter` like this:

```
@Singleton
class AggregationConverter : TypeConverter<String, Aggregation> {
    override fun convert(
        value: String,
        targetType: Class<Aggregation>,
        context: ConversionContext
    ): Optional<Aggregation> = Optional.of(Aggregation.from(value))
}
```

Any advice on this issue will be highly appreciated.

**Environment**
Micronaut: 4.0.0, Kotlin 1.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Making it **Nullable**

When using Serdable fields are considered to be non nullable. If you what a a nullable field then add the `@Nullable` annotation onto that field.

Working with a **Default Value**

Additionally you can work with `Bindable` to set the default value.

```java
@Bindable(defaultValue = "")
List<ClassificationAndStats> getSomeProp();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @saw303, but I don't want the fields to be nullable. BR

Comment: @RoarS. Take a look at Bindable. That might solve your issue. A default `""` is converted to an empty list by the conversion service.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again, I will test this. I was hoping for something else; we have a lot of data classes in library repos, hence this solution is not viable for us.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @saw. The final solution was to remove all `@Serdeable` and `@Introspected`. Then we could use the built-in object mapper without any worries. BR